# Terraform loop query

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

**Terraform version used: Terraform v0.12.13, Transit gateway creation**

Trying to create transit gateway using the below terraform script. I am stuck in the `aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation` resource section where I want to add more than one transit_gateway_attachment_id to every single transit_gateway_route_table_id.

This is what I am trying to achieve.
VPC1 can talk to VPC2,3,4,5 and vice versa.
VPC2 can talk to VPC2,5 and vice versa.
VPC3 can talk to VPC1,4,5 snd vice versa.
.
.
Eg: A tgw_route_table (tgw_rt2) which is associated with attachment2(VPC2) should have propagations for attachmentid 2 and 5 only (VPC2 and 5).
etc..

Using the code mentioned, it just add one attachment. I tried using 'for' loop but no luck, please suggest any better way to achieve this.

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway" "aws_tgw" {
        default_route_table_association = "disable"
        default_route_table_propagation = "disable"
        tags = {
                Name = "TGW"
                Env = "Prod"
        }
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "attach_tgw_vpc" {
        count = "${var.no_of_vpc}"
        subnet_ids = ["${element( aws_subnet.example.*.id, count.index )}"]
        transit_gateway_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.aws_tgw.id}"
        vpc_id = "${element( aws_vpc.terraform_vpc.*.id, count.index )}"
        transit_gateway_default_route_table_association = "false"
        transit_gateway_default_route_table_propagation = "false"
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "tgw_rt" {
        count = "${var.no_of_vpc}"
        transit_gateway_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.aws_tgw.id}"
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association" "aws_rt_association" {
        count = "${var.no_of_vpc}"
        transit_gateway_attachment_id  = "${element( aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.attach_tgw_vpc.*.id, count.index )}"
        transit_gateway_route_table_id = "${element( aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.tgw_rt.*.id, count.index )}"
}

resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation" "tgw_rt_propagation" {
        count = "${var.no_of_vpc}"
#       for_each = data.aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.selected
#       transit_gateway_attachment_id = each.value
        transit_gateway_attachment_id  = "${element( aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.attach_tgw_vpc.*.id, count.index )}"
        transit_gateway_route_table_id = "${element( aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.tgw_rt.*.id, count.index )}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you're using Terraform 12, you should probably be using TF 12 syntax.  Whilst the interpolation of variables, functions, resources and data sources was required in TF 11, it's not required in TF 12.

For example,

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "tgw_rt" {
        count = "${var.no_of_vpc}"
        transit_gateway_id = "${aws_ec2_transit_gateway.aws_tgw.id}"
}
```

becomes:

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "tgw_rt" {
        count = var.no_of_vpc
        transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.aws_tgw.id
}
```

But that doesn't answer your question :)  However, your question does reveal that you've perhaps misunderstood the purpose of the TGW Route Table.

The TGW Route Table acts as the "Hub" in your Hub-Spoke Network Architecture (The [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/transit-gateway-isolated-shared.html) explain a common use case for it quite well).

A consequence of this is that you only need to have 1 TGW Route Table (If you're operating in a multi-account setup you'll need to add a resource share using AWS RAM, but you haven't mentioned that so I won't go into it)

The below is untested, if it doesn't work I can give you the exact code tomorrow when I'm in work.

You should only have 1 TGW Route Table

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table" "tgw_rt" {
        count = var.no_of_vpc > 0 ? 1 : 0
        transit_gateway_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway.aws_tgw.id
}
```

Which also changes this code block

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_association" "aws_rt_association" {
        count = var.no_of_vpc
        transit_gateway_attachment_id  = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.attach_tgw_vpc.*.id[count.index]
        transit_gateway_route_table_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.tgw_rt[0].id
}
```

and this one

```
resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table_propagation" "tgw_rt_propagation" {
        count = var.no_of_vpc > 0 ? 1 : 0
        transit_gateway_attachment_id  = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment.attach_tgw_vpc.*.id[count.index]
        transit_gateway_route_table_id = aws_ec2_transit_gateway_route_table.tgw_rt[0].id
}
```

HTH

Comment: I agree with this concept of having a single tgw route table if it's a full mesh. I also need to create couple of tgw route tables since the connection is something specific like this. Vpc1 can talk to vpc2,3,4 whereas vpc2 can talk to vpc1,5 and goes on. This needs more specific route table definition for each attachment. Please help me if I can achieve this using terraform.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Can you do me a favour and re-write your question so that it describes your actual problem then please. This can be done with TF, but in order to help other people with the same problem the Q and A formate works best when the question is as specific as possible. Thanks

Comment: Updated the question. Hope this gives clear idea on what I am trying to achieve.